# Rails redirect_to loses the https protocol and goes to http

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl

When using `redirect_to example_path` in the controller the protocol gets changed to http. I want the protocol to remain the same as the original request e.g. if I'm using https I want to be redirected to https://example_path... and if I'm using http I want to be redirected to http://example_path...

I know I can use `config.force_ssl = true` but I want ssl to be optional.

Comment: Please add your solution as an answer and not as part of the question, then select your solution as the answer.

Answer (score 2):

redirect_to takes a protocol key in its args hash.  You can do

```
redirect_to example_path, protocol: request.protocol
```

and that should get you sorted.  Let me know if that doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks, I found it was a problem with my nginx configuration. I've now got it working without any rails changes

Comment: @JoeWalsh, what was the solution in nginx?

Answer (score 2):

@ruby_newbie's answer didn't work for me.  `redirect_to` with `String` ignored the `protocol` arg.  Also I am using SSL termination with a proxy, so Rail's protocol may not be the same at what user is using.  You could use `only_path`, but I ended up using `protocol: '//'` as follows:

```
redirect_to controller: 'example', action: 'show', protocol: '//'
```

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me was adding a line in my nginx config. I use nginx+unicorn, listening to http in port 3000 and https in port 3001.

Complete configuration file follows, place this in sites-available and replace [...] with something suitable:

```
upstream myapp {
    server unix:/tmp/unicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    listen 3000;
    listen 3001 ssl;
    server_name example.com;

    ssl_certificate [...];
    ssl_certificate_key [...];

    root [...];

    try_files $uri/index.html $uri @myapp;

    location @myapp {
        proxy_pass http://myapp;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme; # I added this line
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
    client_max_body_size 4G;
    keepalive_timeout 10;
}
```

Comment: `proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;` was the solution, thanks.